# Assign a MagicMock instance to return_value of another MagicMock instance

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, magicmock

I'm trying to mock the return value of a MagicMock instance's function, but the result doesn't go as I expected:

```
>>> f = mock.MagicMock() # => <MagicMock id='139903823124048'>
>>> g = mock.MagicMock() # => <MagicMock id='139903823522512'>
>>> f.goo.return_value = g 
>>> g                    # => <MagicMock name='mock.goo()' id='139903823522512'>
```

Instance g hasn't changed but its name changes?
And when I try:

```
>>> f.goo(1,2)
>>> g.zoo('a')
>>> f.goo(3,4)
>>> f.goo.assert_has_calls([call(1,2), call(3,4)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lando/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 969, in assert_has_calls
    ), cause)
  File "/home/lando/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 737, in raise_from
    raise value
AssertionError: Calls not found.
Expected: [call(1, 2), call(3, 4)]
Actual: [call(1, 2), call().zoo('a'), call(3, 4)]
```

Why does g's call become a part of f.goo's call?
Even:

```
>>> f.goo.call_args_list # => [call(1, 2), call(3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour not very intuitive, but is per expectation.
See-

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_has_calls
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.mock_calls

The calls to the returned values are also tracked in the mock_calls.

Use the `any_order` flag.

Comment: So mock simply keeps track of all calls to itself as well as its method calls and attributes (according to method_calls), in a recursive way. And the assignment to return_value can be considered as an attachment to one of the "branches" of the hierarchical calls. That's what I understand.
For the f.goo, the calls are not sequential so I can hardly use the  any_order flag. Anw, thanks for answering.